# Datepicker previous and next button image issue

Tags: css, datepicker

I am working with simple datepicker but issue is previous and next button images are not displaying.

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Which is working fine if the link is like bellow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

But once I am coping **jquery-ui.css** to my local images are not displaying, like bellow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datatable/jquery-ui.css" />
```

In browser console I am getting error like bellow.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/TestProject/css/datatable/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/TestProject/css/datatable/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/TestProject/css/datatable/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/TestProject/css/datatable/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/TestProject/css/datatable/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png"
```

Error is simple it is not finding these images. But I don't know how to fix this issue while keeping **jquery-ui.css** in local.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you host .css file you must also host images.

Comment: Ya but how, can you explain me. Actually I tried to include images in my local then also I am getting same issue. @exabyssus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create the folder(images)** in your **local system**:

```
TestProject/css/datatable/images/
```

**Download** (or) **savaAs** from the following url to the above path with same name and check:

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
```

Comment: @MickeyPatel Welcome :-)